# Force user to click 'OK' option in confirm

Tags: javascript, function, confirm

I don't know if there is an option, but I want to know if there is possibility.

I want to use the "confirm" command, but I want to pop up the confirm window until the user clicks "OK", instead of "Cancel".

Comment: Its not clear if you want to display an additional pop-up if the users clicks cancel or remove cancel button entirely

Comment: I want them them both, but when a person clicks cancel, the window doesn't disappear, until you click ok

Comment: So what would be the point of keeping the `cancel` button?

Comment: @Jessus Check my answer. In the place where I say you clicked cancel, add code to hide the window.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I think he meant "The window shouldn't disappear until you click ok"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in a while-loop like this:

```js
while(!confirm("By clicking OK below, you agree to sell me your soul.")) {}
```

Comment: Ignoring that this is bade practice for ux: It should be mentioned, that this could freeze the browser if the user checks the `Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs` option in the dialog (at least in Chrome), because then it would act like `while(!false) {}`.

Answer (score 2):

Eh? You can actually check the output of the `confirm`, which is a boolean and do as per...

```js
if (confirm("Are you sure?"))
  // Add code here to do what when user clicks Okay.
  alert("You clicked okay!");
else
  // Add code here to do what when user clicks Cancel.
  alert("You clicked cancel!");
```

- <kbd>Ok</kbd>: `true`
- <kbd>Cancel</kbd>: `false`